# How to revert my git remote branch into previous commit in intelliJ?

Tags: git

I had already one PULL Request.
After rebasing my feature branch with the master I changed some files and commit it and pushed into my remote feature branch.
During push IntelliJ told me to rebase the local branch, I did it and resolved the conflict.
But after the next push, my pull request shows so many file changes and lots of commits, That I did not commit.
How to get rid of this.

Comment: When you did your rebase did you do an interactive rebase such that are your changes are ancestors of the new changes (when you do `git log`)? (This is a question not a suggestion)

Comment: I don't remember now, I am new in git. Maybe I did. But how can I resolve my pull request?

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be to create another branch off of `master` (or whatever your PR is going into) and do a `git merge --squash` to make it a single new commit then restart your PR.

Comment: Great :) - I've added that comment as an actual answer so that it's easier to search in the future. I'd suggest editing the title to remove intelliJ as it's not playing much of a role here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to create another branch off of `master` (or whatever your PR is going into) and do a git `merge --squash` to make it a single new commit then restart your PR.